# Solving Triangles Given 3 Sides

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

A triangle is given with sides $a = 6$, $b = 7$, $c = 9$; required to find the angles of the triangle. The solution I'm familiar with is to find the angles using the half-angle formulas for triangles:

$\tan$$A\over 2$$ = \sqrt{(s–b)(s–c)\over s(s–a)}$, where $s$ is the semiperimeter

By thus formula, $\tan$$A\over 2$$= 0.74$ (approx.)

Hence $A = 73°$ (approx.)

Solving for the rest of the angles using the same formula,

$B = 77°$ (approx.)
$C = 79°$ (approx.)

However, these angles obviously don't add up to $180°$. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Law of Cosines is arguably a better approach here...

Comment: See [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

Comment: Check your calculations. I get, for instance, $\tan\frac12A = \sqrt{8/55}\approx 0.381$, so that $A\approx 41.75^\circ$. (But I also concur that the Law of Cosines may be better.)

Comment: @K.Jiang The Law of Cosines isn't better in general, it is only better in this problem because the side lengths are of relatively small magnitude. When dealing with bigger magntudes the half-angle formula proves best for it is suitable for logarithmic calculations.

Comment: @Blue ahh, what a foolish mistake I've been making. I have been treating $s$ as the perimeter rather than the semiperimeter. Thank you for pointing out the flam.